# QTableWidget.item is noneType whenever access to the Cell Item in QTableWidget pyside

Tags: python, pyside2, qtablewidget

Basically i have combo boxes in many rows inside QTableWidget and i want to retrieve all the cells in row in which the combo-box value currentTextChanged.
i have combobox link to the QTableWidget like this,

[image]

and i connect the `updateTableWidget` Listener in this Qcombobox like this,

```
# objTableWidget of QTableWidget
cbxResult = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
cbxResult.addItems(["Matched", "Not Matched"])
objTableWidget.setCellWidget(rowCount, colCount, cbxResult)
cbxResult.currentTextChanged.connect(lambda: self.updateTableWidget(rowCount, colCount, objTableWidget=objTableWidget))
```

and the `self.updateTableWidget` function is,

```
def updateTableWidget(row:int, col:int, objTableWidget:object):
    
    print(objTableWidget.rowCount())
    print(objTableWidget.objectName())
    objCellWidget = objTableWidget.item(row, col)
    strCellVal = objCellWidget.text()
```

the `objCellWidget = objTableWidget.item(row, col)` return a `NoneType` and
`strCellVal = objCellWidget.text()` NoneType has no attribute 'text()'.

the `objCellWidget = objTableWidget.item(row, col)` is working fine with default TableWidget lineEdit but doesn't work with custom Widget like i use Combobox Widget in QTableWidget.

Comment: use `cbxResult.currentTextChanged.connect(lambda *args, row=rowCount, col=colCount, table=objTableWidget: self.updateTableWidget(row, col, objTableWidget=table))
`

Comment: add change to `objCellWidget = objTableWidget.cellWidget(row, col)`. You have not added a QTableWidgetItem to the cell with the setItem() method but a QWidget with the setCellWidget() method so you must use the cellWidget() method to get the widget.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for quick reply,, your first suggestion works perfectly.